# Access SQL query to match column data with row criteria and fetch score

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am building a scorecard where there are few scoring criteria which I have listed in a table as:
[tblMetric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ2bn.png)

The metric sheet has 5 metrics listed and first 3 metrics have 6 criteria ranges and the other 2 has only 2 (>=X,TRUE or FALSE)

1. Metric1 Score is 30
2. Metric2 Score is 30
3. Metric3 Score is 20
4. Metric4 Score is 10
5. Metric5 Score is 10

I have written a query from the user data and pulled the fields and done some calculations to get the desired output. Now I am supposed to score the user based on the output.
User query has columns  - 
Now the output of each user in individual columns for each of these metrics has to be matched with the Metric table and the actual score from the actual score column has to be fetched and assigned to that user.

Any hint or idea as to how to do it would be of great help.

Let me know if I am not clear

More Details: Here is the query where I want to fetch the score if the value of each individual matches the certain criteria. Below is the sample criteria list.

```
SELECT 
[table].Agent, 
Sum([table1].Offered) AS Offered, 
Sum([table1].Answered) AS Answered, 
Sum([table1].Abandoned) AS Abandoned, 
Sum([table1].[Ansd within SLA]) AS [Ansd within SLA], 
Sum([table1].[TotalLoginDur]/[Dayspresent]) AS Login_Time, 
Sum([table1].[ActualBreak]/[Dayspresent]) AS Break_Time, 
Sum([table1].[Handle_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS HandleTime, 
Sum([table1].[Idle_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS IdleTime, 
Sum([table1].[Ring_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS RingTime, 
Sum([table1].[Talk_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS TalkTime, 
Sum([table1].[Hold_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS HoldTime, 
Sum([table1].[Wrapup_Duration])/Sum([table1].[Answered]) AS WrapupTime, 
[table3].SumOfPresentDays AS Dayspresent, 
[table2].QAScore AS QAScore, 

IIf(Sum([table1].[Abandoned])/Sum([table1].[Offered])<=[check criteria],[fetch score based on criteria],0) AS CheckAbdn, 
IIf(Sum([table1].[Ansd within SLA])/Sum([table1].[Offered])>=[check criteria],[fetch score based on criteria],0) AS CheckSLA, 
IIf([Login_Time]>=[check criteria],[fetch score based on criteria],0) AS CheckLogin, 
IIf([Break_Time]<=[check criteria],[fetch score based on criteria],0) AS CheckBreak, 
([CheckAbdn]+[CheckSLA]+[CheckLogin]+[CheckBreak])/4 AS TScore, 


FROM (([table1] LEFT JOIN [table4] ON [table1].Agent = [table4].AgentName) LEFT JOIN [table3] ON [table1].Agent = [table3].Agent) LEFT JOIN [table2] ON [table1].Agent = [table2].Agent

GROUP BY [table1].Agent, [table3].SumOfPresentDays, [table2].QAScore, Year([table1]![RecordDate]), Month([table1]![RecordDate]), [table4].[table4]

HAVING (((Year([table1]![RecordDate]))=[Forms]![Home].[cboYearSel]) AND ((Month([table1]![RecordDate]))=[Forms]![Home].[cboMonthSel]) AND (([table4].[table4])=[Forms]![Home].[cboAgtCatSel]))

ORDER BY Year([table1]![RecordDate]), Month([table1]![RecordDate]);
```

[Criteria sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1THQd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving enough information for an accurate solution but let's first assume you can design your table better where "Metric" is identified by a numerical `MetricID` field and your `To` and `From` range fields are also numerical. You actually don't even need `To` and `From` just the upper (or lower) limit for each score. Finally lets' rename `ID` to `ScoreID` because of many reasons I won't go into but should become obvious as you gain experience with databases.

You can identify the Score like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM tblMetric WHERE MetricID=1 and [To]<=15 ORDER BY [To] DESC
```

This will give you the record matching Metric 1 and a Score of 15.

Comment: Thank u for replying SunKnight0. I thought so that I am not very clear with my question. I am new and not sure how I could share with you a sample db so as you can understand my question better.

Comment: I have edited my question a bit to help you understand my situation better.